# python - Removing duplicate rows under conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
  NoDemande   NoUsager  Sens  IdVehiculeUtilise  Fait  HeurePrevue  HeureDebutTrajet
0 42191000823  001208    +         246Véh         1    08:20:04     08:22:26 
1 42191000822  001208    +         246Véh         1    08:20:04     08:18:56 
2 42191000822  001208    -         246Véh        -99   09:05:03     08:56:26 
3 42191000823  001208    -         246Véh         1    09:05:03     08:56:26 
4 42191000834  001208    +         246Véh         1    16:50:04     16:39:26 
5 42191000834  001208    -         246Véh         1    17:45:03     17:25:10 
6 42192000761  001208    +         246Véh        -1    08:20:04     08:15:07 
7 42192000762  001208    +         246Véh         1    08:20:04     08:18:27 
8 42192000762  001208    -         246Véh        -99   09:05:03     08:58:29 
9 42192000761  001208    -         246Véh        -11   09:05:03     08:58:29
```

I get this data frame from`df[df.duplicated(['NoUsager','NoDemande'],keep=False)]`which ensure my rows being in pair. I want to drop a pair of rows when `NoDemande` are continuous numbers (like 42191000822 and 42191000823, 42192000761 and 42192000762) and the column `HeurePrevue` are the same, which means the records are recorded twice. I have to delete a pair and I'd like to preseve the one with more positive numbers in column `Fait`(at least one greater than 0)

So my result should look like:

```
  NoDemande   NoUsager  Sens  IdVehiculeUtilise  Fait  HeurePrevue  HeureDebutTrajet
0 42191000823  001208    +         246Véh         1    08:20:04     08:22:26 
3 42191000823  001208    -         246Véh         1    09:05:03     08:56:26 
4 42191000834  001208    +         246Véh         1    16:50:04     16:39:26 
5 42191000834  001208    -         246Véh         1    17:45:03     17:25:10 
7 42192000762  001208    +         246Véh         1    08:20:04     08:18:27 
8 42192000762  001208    -         246Véh        -99   09:05:03     08:58:29
```

I know it's something about `OR` logic but I have no idea how to realize it.

Any help will be appreciated~

Comment: why do you keep -99 instead of -11 in the last record?

Comment: because -99 is line 8, and -11 is line 9. I deleted line 6 and 9 as a pair.

Comment: HeurePrevue are not the same between 6 and 9

Comment: 6 and 9 are in pairs because they are the same in `NoDemande`, the same goes to 7 and 8. I deleted 6 and 9 because in `Fait`, both of them are negative while only one negative between 7 and 8. 6 and 7, 8 and 9 are the same in `HeurePrevue`.

Comment: You would better add that last comment in your question because your wording is confusing

Comment: The approach is to sort and score your pairs along with the continuous ones. Adding a few intermediate scoring columns will give you the material to do the OR

Comment: Sort by nodemande, use shift, count the number of positive numbers, max the ties

Comment: Can you specify it a little bit more? Not fully understand what you said.

Comment: You could try using `for i,row in df.iterrows():` to itereate over your rows.

Comment: Are you shure that it is about OR and not AND?

Comment: I think so. The logic of 'No greater than' should be OR

Comment: I mean here:  "I want to drop a pair of rows when NoDemande are continuous numbers or the column HeurePrevue are the same". I think here should be a "and" and not an "or", shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should be an "and"

Comment: OK, I edited your question. Do you have some progress?

Comment: Still trying...

Comment: Tried my solution?:) let me know what goes wrong if it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

My approach on this problem was to make two columns which contain the conditions for a check (same heure and continuous increasing NoDemande). Then iterate over the dataframe dropping the pairs you do not want based on the Fait columns.

It's a bit of a hacky code but this seems to do the trick:

```
# Recreate DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NoDemande': [23, 22, 22, 23, 34, 34, 61, 62, 62, 61],
    'HeurePrevue': [84, 84, 93, 93, 64, 73, 84, 84, 93, 93],
    'Fait': [1, 1, -99, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -99, -11]
    }, columns=['NoDemande', 'Fait', 'HeurePrevue'])

# Make columns which contain conditions for inspection
df['sameHeure'] = df.HeurePrevue.iloc[1:] == df.HeurePrevue.iloc[:-1]
df['cont'] = df.NoDemande.diff()

# Cycle over rows
for prev_row, row in zip(df.iloc[:-1].itertuples(), df.iloc[1:].itertuples()):
    if row.sameHeure and (row.cont == 1):  # If rows are continuous and have the same Heure delete a pair
        pair_1 = df.loc[df.NoDemande == row.NoDemande]
        pair_2 = df.loc[df.NoDemande == prev_row.NoDemande]
        if sum(pair_1.Fait > 0) < sum(pair_2.Fait > 0):  # Find which pair to delete
            df.drop(pair_1.index, inplace=True)
        else:
            df.drop(pair_2.index, inplace=True)

df.drop(['cont', 'sameHeure'], 1, inplace=True)  # Throw away the added columns
```

result:

```
print(df)

   NoDemande  Fait  HeurePrevue
0         23     1           84
3         23     1           93
4         34     1           64
5         34     1           73
7         62     1           84
8         62   -99           93
```

Answer (score 0):

I see here two solutions.
*The first is based on the suggestion, that you have always continuous pairs of entries in your dataset* - that if any entry has a pair, this pair comes after this entry. Then you should loop over your dataframe with step size = 2:

```
for i in range(0,x,2):
  your action
```

And in this loop you can compare your two entries and remove the one that has a negative value.

*My second proposition is a little bit complex.*

First you should copy and lag (shift by specific number of rows) all columns. This can be done with following function (applied only on NoDemande, for doing so to every column use a loop):

```
df.NoDemande = df.NoDemande.shift(-1)
```

It will look like:

```
  NoDemande      NoDemande_lagged

0 42191000823    42191000822
1 42191000822    42191000822 
2 42191000822    42191000823
3 42191000823    42191000834
```

Then compare the two values in the same row in NoDemande and NoDemande_lagged columns. If the number from 42191000822 is greater or smaller by 1 than the value in NoDemande, then compare **Fait** and **Fait_lagged** and choose the more positive value, which you should paste in the new column **Fait_selected**. The same you should do with other columns, so that every column will have a lagged copy and a selected copy. Afterwards you should remove your next row, because you have already compared it with the previous one.
At the end you should delete your original and lagged colums and leave only the "_selected".

Sorry for a complex Explanation, hope, that this will help you anyway. If you are familiar with RapidMiner, I can explain how to do this there, it will be easier. And I gave you some ideas for various concepts that can help you to solve your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-winded solution, there might be shorter ones. `frame0` is the exact frame you posted above.

First take the data, sort it by `NoDemande`, split it and recombine it so you have two pairings in the same row. Makes things a lot easier:

```
frame0.HeurePrevue = pd.to_datetime(frame0.HeurePrevue)
frame0 = frame0.sort_values('NoDemande').reset_index(drop=True)
frameA = frame0.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
frameB = frame0.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
frame1 = pd.concat([frameA,frameB],axis=1,join='inner')
frame1.columns = [u'NoDemande1', u'NoUsager1', u'Sens1', u'IdVehiculeUtilise1', u'Fait1',\
                  u'HeurePrevue1', u'HeureDebutTrajet1', u'NoDemande2', u'NoUsager2', u'Sens2',\
                  u'IdVehiculeUtilise2', u'Fait2', u'HeurePrevue2', u'HeureDebutTrajet2']
frame1 = frame1[[u'NoDemande1', u'Fait1',u'HeurePrevue1', u'NoDemande2',u'Fait2',\
                 u'HeurePrevue2']]
```

Next do some comparisons to see if in a given row the row ABOVE that row is a duplicate or not:

```
frame2 = frame1[['NoDemande1','NoDemande2','HeurePrevue1','HeurePrevue2']].diff()
frame2['lastColumnsPartner'] = (frame2.NoDemande1 == 1) & (frame2.NoDemande2 == 1) &\
                               (frame2.HeurePrevue1 == pd.Timedelta(0)) &\
                               (frame2.HeurePrevue2 == pd.Timedelta(0))
frame2 = frame2['lastColumnsPartner'].to_frame()
frame1 = pd.merge(frame1,frame2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Now check the values of `Fait`:

```
frame1['Fait1Pos'] = 0
frame1['Fait2Pos'] = 0
frame1.ix[frame1.Fait1>0,'Fait1Pos'] = 1
frame1.ix[frame1.Fait2>0,'Fait2Pos'] = 1
frame1['FaitPos'] = frame1.Fait1Pos+frame1.Fait2Pos
frame1['FaitBool'] = (frame1.Fait1 > 0)|(frame1.Fait2 > 0)
```

Iterate over all rows and use the boolean `lastColumnsPartner` to create a new index which identifies duplicate rows:

```
frame1['newIndex'] = 0
j = -1
for i,row in frame1.iterrows():
  if frame1.ix[i,'lastColumnsPartner'] == False:
    j+=1
  frame1.ix[i,'newIndex'] = j
```

Take only rows with at least one positive value in `Fait` (`FaitBool`), sort by number of positive values of `Fait` (`FaitPos`), drop duplicates (`newIndex`) to keep only the highest value of `Fait`, then return `NoDemande`.

```
tokeep = frame1[frame1.FaitBool][['NoDemande1','newIndex','FaitPos']]\
 .sort_values('FaitPos',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('newIndex')['NoDemande1']
```

Finally use boolean indexing on the initial frame to filter everything.

```
frame0 = frame0[frame0.NoDemande.isin(tokeep)]
```

I can't say for sure if it works for all cases, it works for your example. Also there is probably room for improvement.